# In Coldfusion 11 on Datasource Verification, getting the error Timed out trying to establish connection

Tags: oracle, coldfusion, odbc, datasource, coldfusion-11

After an ABNORMAL shutdown of Coldfusion server and Oracle Database server, I started both Database & Coldfusion servers. Then I tried to verify Datasource from Coldfusion Admin, I am getting the below error for few hours.

> Connection verification failed for data source: 
>   java.sql.SQLException: Timed out trying to establish connection. The
>   root cause was that: java.sql.SQLException: Timed out trying to
>   establish connection.

So I created another datasource with different datasource name for the same database. But it worked properly.

After a few hours both datasouces worked.

**Datasource connection Details below:**

**CF Data Source Name**:

> xxxxxxx

**JDBC URL**:

> jdbc:macromedia:oracle://ip_address:port_no;SERVICENAME=;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;MaxPooledStatements=700;AlternateServers=(ip_address:port_no);ConnectionRetryCount=5;ConnectionRetryDelay=5

**Driver Class**:

> macromedia.jdbc.MacromediaDriver

Why I am getting the timeout error after abnormal shutdown? How to fix this issue permanently? Do we need to clean up something like the cache in Coldfusion server?

Comment: How large is the database? Maybe it wasn't fully back on line when you tried to verify the original datasource. An abnormal shutdown can cause a database to run through various integrity checks when it restarts.

Comment: The database is too large. Some table contains more than 100000 records. I tried Verifying datasource for 2-3 hours. But the same database connection from another JAVA Application works perfectly.

Comment: 100K records isn't a whole lot, unless they are very wide tables with heavy datatypes. If it's taking 2-3 hours just to verify the datasource, then you have another issue somewhere. There may be some corruption, especially after an abnormal shutdown. I would suggest a hard integrity check of that database (and a backup). What version of Oracle?